# Add a lighting effect near navbar brand to background

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

i'm trying to apply a lighting effect similar to the one linked below to the website i'm making. I'm not sure exactly where to start and I can't find any similar questions online or on stack overflow. Any pointers?

[image]

Comment: You mean that glossy looking navbar like this? [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5ye9n81f/). Use [css3 gradients](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp), I used [colorzilla](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) to create it tho.

Comment: That's one of the things I was trying to implement. So essentially using that as a background for a part of the navbar to appear like buttons.

Comment: What i'm mainly referring to is the subtle lighting effect on the background of the ITCONSULTANTS text. I'd like the make a portion of the background subtly lighter.

Comment: Oh that, that can also be done using gradients (radial). Other way would be using a background image. If you have the link to the above website you can check how they implemented it.

Comment: Created this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gh81o7j0/) to show how you can do it using gradients.

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS3 gradients with `ul` and `li` tags

```css
#my-nav {
  
background: rgb(254,204,177); /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(254,204,177,1) 0%, rgba(241,116,50,1) 34%, rgba(234,85,7,1) 61%, rgba(251,149,94,1) 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(254,204,177,1) 0%,rgba(241,116,50,1) 34%,rgba(234,85,7,1) 61%,rgba(251,149,94,1) 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(254,204,177,1) 0%,rgba(241,116,50,1) 34%,rgba(234,85,7,1) 61%,rgba(251,149,94,1) 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#feccb1', endColorstr='#fb955e',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
border-radius: 7px;
}
#my-nav a {
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul class="nav" id="my-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" href="#">ABOUT</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">BLOG</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">SOLUTIONS</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">BOOKS</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like kiranvj said.
Use CSS3 Gradients, you can [generate your Gradient on this Site](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/)

They even got a similar Preset i think its called "Orange Gloss".

When you are happy with your Gradient (Top Right you have a Preview)
just copy the code and use it in your stylesheet.

But keep an Eye on the Compatibility!